# Can not pass W3C validator check if <aside> tag is contained within <p> tag

Tags: html

The following HTML can not pass W3C HTML 5 validator (http://validator.w3.org/check) check:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
<title>Test</title> <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
 <p>
    This is a demo.
    <aside >
        <p>Aside element node.</p>
    </aside>
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But if change the p tag to others, for example, div tag, it will pass the W3C validator check:

```
<div>
    This is a demo.
    <aside >
        <p>Aside element node.</p>
    </aside>
</div>
</body>
```

Why?

Comment: [aside](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-aside-element.html#the-aside-element): "It's not appropriate to use the aside element just for parentheticals, since those are part of the main flow of the document."

Comment: That should be an answer, not a comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Aside` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-aside-element.html#the-aside-element) is:

> a *section* of a page that consists of content that is tangentially related to the content...

(Emphasis added)

It is [Flow Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#flow-content). A [`p` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-p-element.html#the-p-element) represents a paragraph, and contains [Phrasing Content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/content-models.html#phrasing-content), which is defined as:

> the text of the document, as well as elements that mark up that text at the intra-paragraph level. Runs of phrasing content form paragraphs.

and notes:

> Most elements that are categorized as phrasing content can only contain elements that are themselves categorized as phrasing content, not any flow content.

So, it's flagged as not passing because - it doesn't conform to HTML5, per the spec.

Also, from the page on aside:

> It's not appropriate to use the aside element just for parentheticals, since those are part of the main flow of the document.

gives another hint that this is inappropriate usage.

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help.
The following links are very useful also:

[Content categories](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Content_categories)

[P Tag](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/p)

[aside Tag](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/aside)